# Radial gradient sometimes invisible when size is small

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a background that looks like a grid of circles. I need it to be configurable, so I want to do this in CSS instead of just using an image. As of now i'm accomplishing this via radial-gradient.

```
radial-gradient(black 3px, white 3px);
```

I'm running into an issue though. Part of the reason it's configurable is that the user can scale everything up/down. When it gets scaled down too much though, it becomes invisible. This happens when I set the circles to be .6 x .6

https://jsfiddle.net/joLt26u0/

Minimum size that works:

```js
var background = document.querySelector(".dotBackground");

// invisible
// background.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(black ${.6}px, white ${.6}px)`;

// smallest while still visible
background.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(black ${.7}px, white ${.7}px)`;
```

```css
.dotBackground{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-size: 40px 40px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="dotBackground"></div>
```

Invisible:

```js
var background = document.querySelector(".dotBackground");

// invisible
background.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(black ${.6}px, white ${.6}px)`;

// smallest while still visible
// background.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(black ${.7}px, white ${.7}px)`;
```

```css
.dotBackground{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-size: 40px 40px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="dotBackground"></div>
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Does anyone know why this is happening or a solution? If not, is there alternative CSS I can use to achieve the same thing? I just need a grid background of circles where I can configure the color/space between dots/size of dots.

Comment: It's because of the .6px (it has to be >1px), how are you setting this value, through JavaScript? If so, can you add it?

Comment: Updated OP. It works at .7px and then starts having issues at .6px.